# Cron job is not working-cpanel VPS Optimized 3

Tags: php, cron

This is my code. File name is test_cron.php(inside the crtest folder). 
Cron command is: /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/portroot/public_html/crtest/test_cron.php

It should be run on the server every minute. It should generate the text files every minute. But nothing is happen. I gave an email address also. But I didnt get any email. Please help me to correct this.

```
<?php 
//Cron command: /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/portroot/public_html/crtest/test_cron.php

$filename = "./public_html/crtest".time().".txt";
$handle = fopen($filename,'w') or die("Cannot open file");

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    $con = "Hello world \n";
    fwrite($handle,$con);
}
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

u have to do 2 different test :

1. check ur script without using Cron by running it in browser and check if u get the result u want.
2. check ur Cron with a very sample script like an insert query to enter some data to ur database.

Then u can find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below step to check your code and setup cron on server:

**1.** First check your code is successfully running on your local system or not.

**2.** If you need to call a php script using URL; you can simply use lynx, curl or wget. Make sure you've placed your php script within the www or public_html directory and call the path properly on the cronjob.

```
*/2 * * * * wget -q http://localhost/test_cron.php
```

**3.** I've used this command to activate cron job for this.

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/yourfilename.php
```

on mostly server and it works fine.

/usr/bin/php is php binary path (different in some systems ex: freebsd /usr/local/bin/php, linux: /usr/bin/php)